# How to refresh Yii widget without refreshing/changing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I'm having an issue with submitting a TbActiveForm and the renderPartial wiping my page out and displaying only the partial view. I want to reload only the widget after my action triggers and finishes. I'm also using a modal to display and make changes.

view:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget(
     'booster.widgets.TbActiveForm',
     array(
         'id' => 'horizontalForm',
         'type' => 'horizontal',
         'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('orderControl/order/returns.save'),
          )
     );
     echo $form->hiddenField(
          $editReturnFormModel,
          'orderId',
          array(
              'value' => $editReturnFormModel->orderId
         )
     );
     $this->widget(
           'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
           array('buttonType' => 'submit', 'type' => 'primary', 'label' => 'Save')
                        );
     $this->endWidget();
```

Action:

```
$this->controller->renderPartial('ScModules.orderControl.widgets.ReturnsWidget.views._returnItems', array('returnsDataProvider'=>$returnsDataProvider, 'editReturnFormModel'=>$editReturnFormModel));
```

One other point is that the `Yii::app()->createUrl('orderControl/order/returns.save')` is change the page url all together. On this page page I'm directed to, the view is created fine. I need the widget to rebuild/refresh on the current page and not send me somewhere else. Any ideas on solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. Wrap your form widget inside a div or whatever block tag you like.`<div id="myFormWrapper"> (your widget goes here) </div>`
2. Add a custom ID in your form (id="formId") and submit button (id="submitButtonId")
3. **Add some jQuery in order to submit your form and replace the old widget with the new**

```
    $(document).on('click', '#submitButtonId' , function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $('#formId').attr('action'),
            data : $('#formId').serialize(),
            beforeSend : function(){
                    //do anything you want before sending the form
            },
            success : function(data){
                    //We'll replace the old form with the new form widget  
                    $('#myFormWrapper').html(data);

            },
            error : function(data){
                console.log('ops');
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
```

4. Do whatever you want to do in your Controller action and use renderPartial.

```
    //The action below should be the same that you used in the action attribute of the form
    public function actionProcessForm(){
       $model = new MyFormModelName();
       if(isset($_POST['MyFormModelName'])){
          $model->attributes = $_POST['MyFormModelName'];
          if($model->save()){
             //Do whatever you want here
             $returnsDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('YourModel');
             $this->renderPartial('//folder/to/your/view',  array('returnsDataProvider'=> $returnsDataProvider, 'editReturnFormModel'=>$editReturnFormModel));
          }else{
              //You might want to render something else here
              $this->renderPartial('errorViewPage');
          }
       }
    }
```